# Do users upvote questions or answers more?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics, up-votes

According to my profile page, I've voted on 1100 questions and voted on 800 answers. If Q is the number of question votes I've given and A is the number of answer votes, then $Q-A=300$. What is the distribution of $Q-A$ across all users? What about looking at just upvotes?

Comment: My intuition was more upvotes for questions than for answers. It's easier to tell a good question from a bad question than it is to tell a good answer from a bad answer. But Woodface's data shows my intuition was wrong.

Comment: @Alonso: There are many easy to judge answers to not very good questions.

Comment: I am fairly new to stack exchange and usually upvote answers that I have learned something from.  That is far more than the questions which intrigue me, but I will perhaps consider upvoting more questions now.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As of March 15, 2015, Math.SE users cast

- [$891443$ upvotes on questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/289002/total-number-of-votes-of?posttype=1&votetype=2)
- [$1476969$ upvotes on answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/289002/total-number-of-votes-of?posttype=2&votetype=2)
- [$52960$ downvotes on questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/289002/total-number-of-votes-of?posttype=1&votetype=3)
- [$31851$ downvotes on answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/289002/total-number-of-votes-of?posttype=2&votetype=3)

With about 410k questions and 599k answers, the averages are:

- $2.2$ upvotes per question
- $2.5$ upvotes per answer
- $0.13$ downvotes per question
- $0.05$ downvotes per answer

Only the votes on non-deleted posts are counted above.

---

The averages given above mask large differences between individual voters. Back in December 2014, I compiled some statistics for the 17 users who cast at least 10000 votes by that time. The chart distinguishes question votes (blue) from answer votes (green); it includes both up and down votes.

[image: split]

Comment: So this is interesting to me because it means I am somewhat atypical in pivoting questions more than answers.

Comment: I added a chart that shows there is a lot of variability there.

Comment: what do you use to generate the chart?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas This one was 100% manual. I looked at the list of [top voters](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all), navigated to each profile and recorded the votes in a spreadsheet (OpenOffice or Excel, don't remember). The Q vs A split of votes is not available in Data Explorer. This is why I'm showing the data from December: don't feel like doing this exercise again just now.

Comment: Is there any scope of say hooking into the stackexchange API and generating these sorts of tables in an automated fashion?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Not the Q/A split. Up/Down is available: both counts are returned by [/users API method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids). It still takes work to handle the data, in any case.

Comment: If you're interested [here's an updated version of the chart](https://i.imgur.com/cjAxYHA.png) (I didn't know about that API thing, that's great).

Comment: [Here's also a chart of the up/down votes from the top voters](https://i.imgur.com/yMSFxMB.png) (I'm too lazy to sort by number of votes...) The results aren't very surprising.

Comment: Woah, @Woodface's downvote's.

Comment: **As of September 18, 2017:** $1734358$ upvotes on questions, $2768815$ upvotes on answers, $143827$ downvotes on questions and $68408$ downvotes on answers. Seems like we have become more strict with the quality of questions recently.